# Why is my method giving me the null value?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, methods

I dont understand why I am receiving such a value. This method depends on an array directly and another two indirectly. They are all filled with a similar amount of steps however the method by which they are filled varies. Some go from top to zero whereas the others go from null up. I can elaborate more if this doesn't make sense

The alpha value was filled from top down while it was dependent on another array tat was filled from bottom up. Is that allowed?

```
blic class ItrDensityGrid {

public double itrrho [ ];           // defines an a array of adjusted densities

double b = InitialConditions.bmod;  

// Iterating grid of adjusted densities 

public ItrDensityGrid ( int shells , double radius , double mass , double bmod ) {      // Density constructor with inputs

    GravityGrid gg = new GravityGrid ( shells , radius , mass , bmod );             // Pulls gravity array for use, will change each iteration  

    itrrho = new double [ shells + 1 ];                                         // Defines number of elements in array as shells with steps of 1

    for( int k = shells ; k >= 1 ; k -- ){                                  // for loop fills array from top shell down

    itrrho[ k ] = ( itrrho [ k ] * ( 1 + ( gg . alpha [ k ] * ( 1.0 / 2 )))*( 1 / ( 1 - (( gg.alpha[ k ]) * ( 1.0 / 2 )))));   // defines elements form top down

        System.out.println("The adjusted density at shell " + k + " is " + itrrho[k]);

        }
    }

public double itrrho( int k ){

    return( itrrho[ k ] );

    }
}
```

Comment: *I can elaborate more if this doesn't make sense* - Please do. I couldn't comprehend anything.

Comment: Was the sample incomprehensible or my explanation?

Comment: Which method is giving null? And where exactly is it giving null? Are you getting any exceptions because of that?

Comment: for the firsts, this code does not compile coz there a variable `public double itrrho [ ]`and a method `public double itrrho` with the same name which is not allowed.. so, rename either of them...

Comment: what this prints System.out.println("The adjusted density at shell " + k + " is " + itrrho[k]);

Comment: R.J , I am executing this method in the main class with random inputs and i get null all the way down.

Comment: The above code seems to be the epitome of poor designing

Comment: CodeMan, That last method was used to call it in the main class, its just the way I figured this to work

Comment: AJ, the system out print just displayes my values once its executed

Comment: Can you post the main method too?!

Comment: The top part is just the array while the bottom is the actual method. The whole thing is executing. SO that for loop is what is giving me the trouble somewhere.

Comment: The main method is just to call this method with values that it would ask the user

Comment: codeMan, first code ive made. Been learning on the way. This all makes sense to me at least. Thats what happens when you tell a research professor that you can code

Comment: @Alejandro Please dont take my comment the wrong way. Every body is learning :)

Comment: What you mean by null value?

Comment: Just explaining my poor "dialect" thanks though

Comment: AJ, when i run my code for any number of steps (pretty much the number out outputs i can expect) all values are zero. Apparently the goto when the code is unreadable

Answer (score 3):

```
itrrho[ k ] = ( itrrho [ k ] *  ( 1 + ( gg . alpha [ k ] * ( 1.0 / 2 )))*( 1 / ( 1 - (( gg.alpha[ k ]) * ( 1.0 / 2 ))))););
```

here `itrrho[k]` is **not inintialized** hence every element of itrrho will be `0.0`

so `itrrho [ k ] * ( 1 + ( gg . alpha [ k ] * ( 1.0 / 2 )))*( 1 / ( 1 - (( gg.alpha[ k ]) * ( 1.0 / 2 )))))`

will be `0.0 * ( 1 + ( gg . alpha [ k ] * ( 1.0 / 2 )))*( 1 / ( 1 - (( gg.alpha[ k ]) * ( 1.0 / 2 )))))`

hence you are getting `0.0`

do something like this after `new double[shels+1];`

```
for(int i=0;i<itrrho.length;i++){
    itrrho[i]=1.0; //initialization
}
```

then see the result

Comment: hmm what exactly do you mean by not initialized? The other for loops I have in this code run a similar way.

Comment: when you create a double array then you have to put something in it otherwise every element will be by default 0.0. and you are multiplying your result with itrrho[k] which is already having 0.0 so your result is 0.0

Comment: I see. Im prety sure I accomplished that with this line, itrrho = new double [ shells + 1 ];

Comment: @Alejandro check the answer and see how to initialize the array

Comment: this returned values that were:

Comment: odd. I will use some legit values to check this

Comment: AJ, what exactly did this do? It seems redundant because my other arrays in this code seemed to work just fine

Comment: only problem is with your this expression:_ itrrho[ k ] = ( itrrho [ k ] *  ( 1 + ( gg . alpha [ k ] * ( 1.0 / 2 )))*( 1 / ( 1 - (( gg.alpha[ k ]) * ( 1.0 / 2 ))))););   you are multiplying with itrrho[k] which is by default 0.0. So remove the itrrho[k] * from your expresion then this will work

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the class or else the array wont be populated.

```
public class TestItrDensityGrid{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ItrDensityGrid grid = new ItrDensityGrid ( 5 , 10.0 , 10.0 , 5.0 );

        System.out.println(grid.itrrho( 5 ));
    }
}
```